# Как осуществить подзапрос Insert SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Не могу понять, почему при выполнении запроса изменяются все атрибуты поля Длительность обучения. Нужно чтобы менялось только то поле, в котором содержится ДИСЦ.Б.11.0

```
update Группы
set [Группы].[Длительность обучения] = [Группы].[Длительность обучения] + 4
(select * from [Дисциплина в семестре] join [Группы] on Группы.[ID группы] = [Дисциплина в семестре].[ID группы]
 where [Дисциплина в семестре].[Код дисциплины] = 'ДИСЦ.Б.11.0')
```

Comment: Что-то Ваш запрос даже синтаксически - неверный... Укажите, о какой СУБД речь.

Comment: Используемая СУБД: SSMS

Comment: SSMS - это клиентское ПО. А СУБД - вероятно, SQL Server, он же MS SQL?

Comment: Да, Вы правы, MS SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
UPDATE [Группы]
SET [Группы].[Длительность обучения] = [Группы].[Длительность обучения] + 4
FROM [Группы]
JOIN [Дисциплина в семестре] ON [Группы].[ID группы] = [Дисциплина в семестре].[ID группы]
WHERE [Дисциплина в семестре].[Код дисциплины] = N'ДИСЦ.Б.11.0'
```

[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=91527e754cde67bb5a274a416f6bdd26)

Comment: К сожалению, не сработало

Comment: @Saintka Обязано работать. См. fiddle. Или Вы неверно переносите решение в свою схему.

Comment: Спасибо большое, забыл указать кодировку, запрос сработал
WHERE [Дисциплина в семестре].[Код дисциплины] =N 'ДИСЦ.Б.11.0'